# Better way to use guards in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, frontend

I would like to know what is the best way to use the "guards" in Angular to know if a user is logged in. Right now I'm asking if the token is in the Storage. My question is if I could make an endpoint in my API in which a request is made and it answers if the user is authenticated.

This is my code:

```
canActivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storageService
        .get(AuthConstants.AUTH)
        .then(res => {
          if (res) {
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
            resolve(false);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          resolve(false);
        });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very obscure way of doing it. First of all, your current code could look like this with the same functionality, but increased readability:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
  return from(this.storageService.get(AuthConstants.Auth)).pipe(
    tap((res) => res || throwError()),
    catchError(() => this.router.createUrlTree(['login']))
  );
}
```

This way the redirect is handled by the angular guard handler. Instead of calling `this.storageService.get(AuthConstants.Auth)` you can call any API you want. Just make sure that whatever you are returning is an `Observable` that actually completes (or a `Promise`, this "always" completes)